# How to sanitize user-submitted mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sanitize

I have never asked a question before because I tend to always find what I need either here or in nixcraft.

I was hoping for a little guidance regarding an application that will be consumed only by technical people within my organization.  They need to be able to query the database, but because of the sensitive nature of the information we do not want them to be able to export a data dump.  I'm sure there are other risks to watch out for, but am really not sure what these risks may be.  The only sanitizing I can think of would be to check for sql syntax issues, and to prevent any kind of statement that would produce a data dump.

The script will be written in PHP without any kind of external library.  Database permissions will be limited to SELECT, so there will be no updating, inserting, dropping, etc...  We will not be able to take advantage of PDO prepared statements because our users will be entering the entire SQL query from start to finish.

Any thoughts you may have would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i think you need repotico or my admin like tools ...:)you dont have to rebuilt a new application

Comment: What exactly do you mean by exporting a data dump? A `SELECT … INTO OUTFILE …`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip Arun.  Yes SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE or a query that might return similar output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowing users to enter entire queries just to `SELECT`, don't. This would be a security nightmare.

Instead, use PDO's prepares and allow users to do advanced searching; to do otherwise would require an AI's level of sanitizing, and if you were doing that, you wouldn't be asking this question.

Instead, ask yourself what logic you need for record searching. Do you need to search multiple fields? If you need joins, you can implicitly (and automatically) join the tables together when you fetch records.
You can also use parameters for `LIMIT`, pagination, and all manner of things *in a form*

---

The basic point is this: ***if a user can write an SQL query, you might as well just give them a login to your SQL console and ignore all sanitizing***. Sanitizing input when a user is writing their own query would be rather strange, and could result in the query not even running.

Comment: After further clarification from other teams it is clear that the only thing I need to protect against is data dumps, which I think I can handle through MySQL with FILE permissions.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the fields that your queries will use as user-provided data and run them through [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) first.

This assumes that you're exposing only a form with the fields that you want them to search on and not something that allows them to enter a full query.

HTH